# How to handle 302 with Retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I would like to know how should I handle `302` using Retrofit 1.9 with connection url 2.5 and OkHttp 2.5 (old project). I need to 'grab' header and check if there is redirect url - if yes, request was successful.

As I understand from this post: [How do you prevent Retrofit from automatically following a 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127626/how-do-you-prevent-retrofit-from-automatically-following-a-302) is that I should `setRedirectStrategy`.
Is `setRedirectStrategy` the best apprach for this?
Current Adapter look like this:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(getFullyConfiguredClient(environment))
                .setLogLevel(environment.getLogLevel()).
                        setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setEndpoint(createEndpoint(environment.getRequestEndpointUrl()))
                .build()

getFullyConfiguredClient()
```

is returning an retrofit.client.Client instance

Comment: So did you try with `setRedirectStrategy`? Something doesn't work?